# How do I include a pipe | in my linux find -exec command?

Tags: linux, command-line

This isn't working.  Can this be done in find?  Or do I need to xargs?

```
find -name 'file_*' -follow -type f -exec zcat {} \| agrep -dEOE 'grep' \;
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The job of interpreting the pipe symbol as an instruction to run multiple processes and pipe the output of one process into the input of another process is the responsibility of the shell (/bin/sh or equivalent).

In your example you can either choose to use your top level shell to perform the piping like so:

```
find -name 'file_*' -follow -type f -exec zcat {} \; | agrep -dEOE 'grep'
```

In terms of efficiency this results costs one invocation of find, numerous invocations of zcat, and one invocation of agrep.

This would result in only a single agrep process being spawned which would process all the output produced by numerous invocations of zcat.

If you for some reason would like to invoke agrep multiple times, you can do:

```
find . -name 'file_*' -follow -type f \
    -printf "zcat %p | agrep -dEOE 'grep'\n" | sh
```

This constructs a list of commands using pipes to execute, then sends these to a new shell to actually be executed.  (Omitting the final "| sh" is a nice way to debug or perform dry runs of command lines like this.)

In terms of efficiency this results costs one invocation of find, one invocation of sh, numerous invocations of zcat and numerous invocations of agrep.

The most efficient solution in terms of number of command invocations is the suggestion from Paul Tomblin:

```
find . -name "file_*" -follow -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zcat | agrep -dEOE 'grep'
```

... which costs one invocation of find, one invocation of xargs, a few invocations of zcat and one invocation of agrep.

Comment: Another advantage of xargs would be, that you can speed it with modern multi core cpu even more up, by using the -P switch (-P 0).

Comment: Yes, the -P swich is indeed a nice way to speed up execution in general. Unfortunately, you run the risk of the output of parallel zcat processes being piped into agrep interleaved, which would affect the result.  This effect can be demonstrated using: echo -e "1\n2" | xargs -P 0 -n 1 yes | uniq

Comment: @Adam, I've made your suggested change.

Comment: for which you can install the splendid xjobs command (originally from Solaris)

Comment: What a beast the printf with sh. You rock.

Comment: A simpler and more general answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21825690/42973: `-exec sh -c "… | … " \;`.

Comment: while this is handy to know, it's not what the question asked.

Comment: The third command (the one that uses `xargs`) is the one that has safeguards against spaces and carriage returns in filenames.

Answer (score 399):

the solution is easy: execute via sh

```
... -exec sh -c "zcat {} | agrep -dEOE 'grep' " \;
```

Comment: What the OP was trying to accomplish can be met with the suggestions above, but this is the one which actually answers the question asked. There are reasons to do it this way - exec is a lot more powerful than just operating on the files returned by find, especially when combined with test. For instance:


find geda-gaf/ -type d -exec bash -c 'DIR={}; [[ $(find $DIR -maxdepth 1 |xargs grep -i spice |wc -l) -ge 5 ]] && echo $DIR' \;


Will return all directories in the search path which contain more than 5 lines total among all the files in that directory containing the word spice

Comment: Best answer. Grepping the whole output (as other answers suggest) isn't the same as grep each file. Tip: instead of sh, you can use any other shell you want (I tried that with bash and it's running ok).

Comment: Make sure to not overlook the `-c` option. Otherwise you will get a puzzling `No such file or directory` error message.

Comment: here's a great ps replacement that makes use of find with piping inside an exec'd shell: /usr/bin/find /proc -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]+' -print -exec bash -c "cat {}/cmdline | tr '\\0' ' ' ; echo" \;

Comment: Example of finding files and renaming them with **sed** using regular expression  `find -type f -name '*.mdds' -exec sh -c "echo {} | sed -e 's/_[0-9]\+//g' | xargs mv {}" \;`

Comment: On AIX the {} inside the quotes is not replaced with the filename, therefore this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Roland try to double quote the brackets and single quotes on the outer scope  `-type f -exec sh -c 'echo "{}"' | grep something\;`

Comment: This doesn't guaranteed that whatever `{}` expands to is quoted properly for the shell. Better to pass `{}` as an argument, e.g. `-exec sh -c 'zcat "$1" | agrep -dEoE "grep" ' _ {} \;` (where `_` is just a dummy argument used to set `$0` in the shell that gets executed).

Answer (score 17):

```
find . -name "file_*" -follow -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zcat | agrep -dEOE 'grep'
```

Comment: Hoping to avoid -print and xargs for efficiency reasons.  Maybe that's really my problem:  find cannot handle piped commands through -exec

Comment: This doesn't work with files with spaces in their names; to fix, replace -print with -print0 and add the -0 option to xargs

Comment: @someguy - Wha? Avoiding xargs for efficiency reasons? Calling one instance of zcat, and passing it a list of multiple files, is *far* more efficient than exec-ing a new instance of it for each found file.

Comment: @Adam - I've made your suggested change.  99% of the time when I'm doing finds, it's in my source code directories, and none of the files there have spaces so I don't bother with print0.  Now my documents directory, on the other hand, I remember the print0.

Comment: Would be a great answer with a little explanation about `-print0`, `xargs -0`, and filename with spaces.

Answer (score 12):

You can also pipe to a `while` loop that can do multiple actions on the file which `find` locates. So here is one for looking in `jar` archives for a given java class file in folder with a large distro of `jar` files

```
find /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins -type f -name \*.jar | while read jar; do echo $jar; jar tf $jar | fgrep IObservableList ; done
```

the key point being that the `while` loop contains multiple commands referencing the passed in file name separated by semicolon and these commands can include pipes. So in that example I echo the name of the matching file then list what is in the archive filtering for a given class name. The output looks like:

/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.core.contenttype.source_3.4.1.R35x_v20090826-0451.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.2.0.M20090902-0800.jar
org/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/list/**IObservableList**.class
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.search.source_3.5.1.r351_v20090708-0800.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.source_3.3.202.R35x_v20091130-2300.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.cvs.source_1.0.400.v201002111343.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.help.appserver_3.1.400.v20090429_1800.jar

in my bash shell (xubuntu10.04/xfce) it really does make the matched classname bold as the `fgrep` highlights the matched string; this makes it really easy to scan down the list of hundreds of `jar` files that were searched and easily see any matches.

on windows you can do the same thing with:

```
for /R %j in (*.jar) do @echo %j & @jar tf %j | findstr IObservableList
```

note that in that on windows the command separator is '&' not ';' and that the '@' suppresses the echo of the command to give a tidy output just like the linux find output above; although `findstr` is not make the matched string bold so you have to look a bit closer at the output to see the matched class name. It turns out that the windows 'for' command knows quite a few tricks such as looping through text files...

enjoy

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a simple alternative, this can be done using a loop:

```
for i in $(find -name 'file_*' -follow -type f); do
  zcat $i | agrep -dEOE 'grep'
done
```

or, more general and easy to understand form:

```
for i in $(YOUR_FIND_COMMAND); do
  YOUR_EXEC_COMMAND_AND_PIPES
done
```

and replace any {} by $i in YOUR_EXEC_COMMAND_AND_PIPES

Answer (score 5):

I found that running a string shell command (sh -c) works best, for example:

```
find -name 'file_*' -follow -type f -exec bash -c "zcat \"{}\" | agrep -dEOE 'grep'" \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you should do:

```
find -name 'file_*' -follow -type f -exec sh -c 'zcat "$1" | agrep -dEOE "grep"' sh {} \;
```

I tried a couple of these answers and they didn't work for me. @flolo's answer doesn't work correctly if your filenames have special characters. [According to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243098/101311):

> The `find` command executes the command directly. The command, including the filename argument, will not be processed by the shell or anything else that might modify the filename. It's very safe.

[You lose that safety if you put the `{}` inside the sh command string.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700643/how-do-i-handle-strange-path-characters-when-piping-find-output)

There is a *potential* problem with @Rolf W. Rasmussen's answer. Yes, it handles special characters (as far as I know), but if the `find` output is too long, you won't be able to execute `xargs -0 ...`: there is a command line character limit set by the kernel and sometimes your shell. Coincidentally, every time I want to pipe commands from a `find`, I run into this limit.

But, they do bring up a valid point regarding the performance limitations. I'm not sure how to overcome that, though personally, I've never run into a situation where my example is too slow.