# Why | doesn't work with find?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why does the following command aiming to remove recursively all .svn folders

```
   find . -name ".svn" | rm -rfv
```

doesn't work ?

I know the `find` command provides the `-exec` option to solve this issue but I just want to understand what is happening there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your example, the results from `find` are passed to `rm`'s STDIN. `rm` doesn't expect its arguments in STDIN, though.

[Here](http://www.dsj.net/compedge/shellbasics1.html) is an example how input redirecting works.

Comment: Finally! Someone actually answers the question!

Comment: Each reply answers the why, although some are a bit cryptic.

Answer (score 2):

`rm` does not read file names from standard input, so any data piped to it is ignored.

The only thing it uses standard input for is checking whether it's a terminal, so it can determine whether to prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because rm does not accept a list of file names on its standard input stream.

Just for reference, the safest way to handle this in the case of directories that might contain spaces is:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -frv {} \;
```

Or, if you are shooting for speed:

```
find . -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -frv
```

Comment: And if you read the **rest** of the question: *"I know the `find` command provides the `-exec` option to solve this issue but I just want to understand what is happening there."*. **Edit**: Okay, now you've edited enough to deal with it.

Comment: I would expect (without testing) that `-exec rm -frv {} +` is fastest, since it has the fewest processes.

Answer (score 1):

find do works with | ( for example `find ~ -name .svn | grep "a"`) but the problem is with `rm`

Comment: Exactly. That's because `grep` *expects* input from STDIN, whereas `rm` ignores anything piped to it and wants parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to this other answered question. Hope this helps.

[How do I include a pipe | in my linux find -exec command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307015/how-do-i-include-a-pipe-in-my-linux-find-exec-command)