# How to parallelize my bash script for use with `find` without facing race conditions?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I am trying to execute a command like this:

```
find ./ -name "*.gz" -print -exec ./extract.sh {} \;
```

The `gz` files themselves are small. Currently my `extract.sh` contains the following:

```
# Start delimiter
echo "#####" $1 >> Info
zcat $1 > temp
# Series of greps to extract some useful information
grep -o -P "..." temp >> Info
grep -o -P "..." temp >> Info
rm temp
echo "####" >> Info
```

Obviously, this is not parallelizable because if I run multiple `extract.sh` instances, they all write to the same file. What is a smart way of doing this?

I have 80K `gz` files on a machine with massive horse power of 32 cores.

Comment: Is there any reason that you couldn't use a separate temp file for each file you're extracting?

Comment: uuoc: `cat temp | grep` is redundant, grep accepts input files as an argument.

Comment: I wanted a single aggregate file in the end and am looking for the most efficient way of doing this. In my case, this would mean creating an additional 80K files. Do you think it won't matter?

Comment: @ChrisBrowne: Yeap. Just changed it.

Comment: Now that I think about it, couldn't you just `zcat $1 | grep blah`?

Comment: Maybe you can write a daemon script that tries to merge any two files in the output directory. If order is necessary, number the generated `Info` files.

Comment: @K.G.: Actually I have multiple greps and am doing some post-processing to the output so I did not want to do multiple `zcat`s which is why I created a temp file first. I would be open to any improvements though.

Comment: Well, if you're looking for multiple patterns, then you can always `grep -e thing1 -e thing2` to find both.  Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307015/how-do-i-include-a-pipe-in-my-linux-find-exec-command).  Based on what you have here, I believe you could do away with `extract.sh` entirely by using unnamed pipes.

Comment: creation of the temp file is redundant. You can use tee to pipe output to multiple processes (`cat file | tee >(./process1.sh) >(./process2.sh)`. But using a temp file is more readable and there are functions to help you create unique temp files.

Comment: @K.G.: Thank You. I am now making another attempt at this. In the question that you linked, the third comment by RolfWRasmussen is the problem I am facing. When I pipe the output to one file even when using xargs, the output gets interleaved.

Comment: @K.G.: Also, is there a way I can maintain order when `grep`ping for multiple patterns? This is the only reason why I am doing multiple separate greps. If there is a way to say: `grep -e '(1)..." -e "(2)..."` or something close, that would be great.

Comment: You can pipe the output of your grep to `sort`.  You're still (likely) going to run into the issue of interleaving your results if you're running this in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a temporary directory. Then create an output file for each grep (based on the name of te file it processed). Files created under `/tmp` are located on a RAM disk and so will not thrash your harddrive with lots of writes.

You can then either cat it all together at the end, or get each grep to signal another process when it has finished and that process can begin catting files immediately (and removing them when done).

Example:

```
working_dir="`pwd`"
temp_dir="`mktemp -d`"
cd "$temp_dir"
find "$working_dir" -name "*.gz" | xargs -P 32 -n 1 extract.sh 
cat *.output > "$working_dir/Info"
rm -rf "$temp_dir"
```

extract.sh

```
 filename=$(basename $1)
 output="$filename.output"
 extracted="$filename.extracted"
 zcat "$1" > "$extracted"

 echo "#####" $filename > "$output"
 # Series of greps to extract some useful information
 grep -o -P "..." "$extracted" >> "$output"
 grep -o -P "..." "$extracted" >> "$output"
 rm "$extracted"
 echo "####" >> "$output"
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer was downvoted. Also, there is a slight problem with this. When `output="$1.output"` it is not creating the tmp files in the tmp directory but rather in the original directory.

Comment: Modified it to a working version by using `$(basename $1)` to extract the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Assume (just for simplicity and clearness) all your files starts with a-z.

So you could use 26 cores in parallel when launching an find sequence like above for each letter. Each "find" need to generate an own aggregate file

```
find ./ -name "a*.gz" -print -exec ./extract.sh a {} \; &
find ./ -name "b*.gz" -print -exec ./extract.sh b {} \; &
..
find ./ -name "z*.gz" -print -exec ./extract.sh z {} \;
```

(extract needs to take to first parameter to separate the "info" destination file)

When you want a big aggregate file just joins all aggregate.

However, I am not convinced to gain performance with that approach. In the end all file content will be serialized.

Probably hard disk head movement will be the limitation not the unzip (cpu) performance.

But let's try

Comment: +1 for the idea. However, I somehow get the feeling that there is a one-liner solution that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

A quick check through the findutils source reveals that find starts a child process for each exec. I believe it then moves on, though I may be misreading the source. Because of this you are already parallel, since the OS will handle sharing these out across your cores. And through the magic of virtual memory, the same executables will *mostly* share the same memory space.

The problem you are going to run into is file locking/data mixing. As each individual child runs, it pipes info into your `info` file. These are individual script commands, so they will mix their output together like spaghetti. This does not guarantee that the files will be in order! Just that all of an individual file's contents will stay together.

To solve this problem, all you need to do is take advantage of the shell's ability to create a temporary file (using `tempfile`), have each script dump to the temp file, then have each script `cat` the temp file into the `info` file. Don't forget to delete your temp file after use.

If the tempfiles are in ram(see [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs)), then you will avoid being IO bound except when writing to your final file, and running the find search.

Tmpfs is a special file system that uses your ram as "disk space". It will take up to the amount of ram you allow, not use more than it needs from that amount, and swap to disk as needed if it does fill up.

To use:

1. Create a mount point ( I like /mnt/ramdisk or /media/ramdisk )
2. Edit /etc/fstab as root
3. Add `tmpfs /mnt/ramdrive tmpfs size=1G  0 0`
4. Run umount as root to mount your new ramdrive. It will also mount at boot.

See the [wikipedia entry on fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) for all the options available.

Comment: +1 Thank You. Could you please elaborate on your third paragraph? I am currently looking into the tmpfs.

Comment: @Legend sure. For a tiny example project using tmpfs, see my port of the [ffox-daemon](https://github.com/srathbun/firefox-tmpfs-daemon) to debian. I'll also edit my answer with details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` to run your search in parallel. `--max-procs` limits number of processes executed (default is 1):

```
find ./ -name "*.gz" -print | xargs --max-args 1 --max-procs 32 ./extract.sh
```

In the `./extract.sh` you can use `mktemp` to write data from each `.gz` to a temporary file, all of which may be later combined:

```
# Start delimiter
tmp=`mktemp -t Info.XXXXXX`
src=$1
echo "#####" $1 >> $tmp
zcat $1 > $tmp.unzip
src=$tmp.unzip

# Series of greps to extract some useful information
grep -o -P "..." $src >> $tmp
grep -o -P "..." $src >> $tmp
rm $src
echo "####" >> $tmp
```

If you have massive horse power you can use `zgrep` directly, without unzipping first. But it may be faster to `zcat` first if you have many `grep`s later.

Anyway, later combine everything into a single file:

```
cat /tmp/Info.* > Info
rm /tmp/Info.*
```

If you care about order of `.gz` files apply second argument to `./extract.sh`:

```
find files/ -name "*.gz" | nl -n rz | sed -e 's/\t/\n/' | xargs --max-args 2 ...
```

And in `./extract.sh`:

```
tmp=`mktemp -t Info.$1.XXXXXX`
src=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

The multiple `grep` invocations in `extract.sh` are probably the main bottleneck here.  An obvious optimization is to read each file only once, then print a summary in the order you want.  As an added benefit, we can speculate that the report can get written as a single block, but it might not prevent interleaved output completely.  Still, here's my attempt.

```
#!/bin/sh

for f; do
    zcat "$f" |
    perl -ne '
        /(pattern1)/ && push @pat1, $1;
        /(pattern2)/ && push @pat2, $1;
        # ...
        END { print "##### '"$1"'\n";
            print join ("\n", @pat1), "\n";
            print join ("\n", @pat2), "\n";
            # ...
            print "#### '"$f"'\n"; }'
done
```

Doing this in `awk` instead of Perl might be slightly more efficient, but since you are using `grep -P` I figure it's useful to be able to keep the same regex syntax.

The script accepts multiple `.gz` files as input, so you can use `find -exec extract.sh {} \+` or `xargs` to launch a number of parallel processes.  With `xargs` you can try to find a balance between sequential jobs and parallel jobs by feeding each new process, say, 100 to 500 files in one batch.  You save on the number of new processes, but lose in parallelization.  Some experimentation should reveal what the balance should be, but this is the point where I would just pull a number out of my hat and see if it's good enough already.

Granted, if your input files are small enough, the multiple `grep` invocations will run out of the disk cache, and turn out to be faster than the overhead of starting up Perl.