# system wide elf compression script using find, file, and upx

Tags: bash, shell, unix, elf, upx

I'm working on my first script, and it is to compress all elf executables on a system.

```
  find / * -executable -type f -exec file '{}' \; | grep ELF | sed -e "s/[:].*//" |     
  upx --best --ultra-brute
```

upx is not responding to sent files

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include a pipe | in my linux find -exec command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307015/how-do-i-include-a-pipe-in-my-linux-find-exec-command)

Comment: maybe, I'll change it in a sec if that's the case.  I didn't know that's what I was looking at, if so.

Comment: John, you're right on this one.

Comment: Don't use `for i in $(find)` - use `find -exec` or `find -print0 | -xargs -0` (with a more complex `-exec` or `xargs` clause). By the way, the problem is that you're using `{}` instead of `$()`. The line continuation backslashes aren't necessary. Remove the asterisk - it's only getting in the way.

Comment: Dennis, that is less than helpful.  The context is 'my first bash script'.

Comment: @Josh - He gave you specific examples on what was wrong and what you should use instead. Why isn't that helpful?

Comment: I don't *want* to discourage you, but is it wise to use your first script for something so critical? Is it even wise to compress everything indiscriminately? Modifying the core libraries like this is not for the lighthearted and may have all sort of unintended side-effects. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @jordanm yeah, you're right

Comment: @thkala This did byte my system.  Good practice, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you're going a safe way for your system (don't you want to filter at least shared libs?), but I would suggest:

```
find / -executable -type f | xargs file |\
grep ELF | cut -d: -f1 | xargs upx --best --ultra-brute
```

If you have blanks in file names

```
find / -executable -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file |\
grep ELF | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -0 upx --best --ultra-brute
```

but is is likely you will bump into a shell limit (xargs: argument line too long)

One workaround would be to use a loop:

```
find / -executable -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file |\
grep ELF | cut -d: -f1 |\
while read f 
do
   upx --best --ultra-brute "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include pipe in the `exec` argument. I do that with `sh -c`:

```
find / * -executable -type f -exec sh -c 'file '{}' \
| grep -q ELF' \; -print \
| upx --best --ultra-brute
```

Also I use here `-print` instead of your construction with `sed`. It's better because in case you have `:` in a filename, sed-based solution will not work (even better is `-print0` with `xargs -0`).