# find file names that return success on -exec command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

I am using find to find names of databases that return some rows for a query.

```
$ find . -name 'sqlite.db' -exec sqlite3 "{}" 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1="value"' \; 

value|a|b|c|d
```

But I want the name of the database, so I tried -print which showed all the names

```
$ find . -name 'sqlite.db' -print -exec sqlite3 "{}" 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1="value"' \; 

/dir1/a/sqlite.db
value|a|b|c|d
/dir2/a/sqlite.db
/dir2/b/sqlite.db
/dir3/a/sqlite.db
```

Is there a way I can get only the files where the exit status of the command run is success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to `-print` after the `-exec`.  It is a short circuiting boolean `and`, and by putting `-print` before `-exec`, the print happens before the exec does.

```
find . -name sqlite.db -exec ... \; -print
```

Answer (score 1):

sqite3 returns 0 even when there is not data is found matching the criteria. It returns false only when there is a error in the sql statement itself or in the arguments passed.

```
sqlite3 sqlite.db 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1="value"'
```

will return 0 even there is no matchin column in the database. You can combine command with grep for the find to work.

```
sqlite3 sqlite.db 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1="value" | grep value
```

so your find command becomes

```
find . -name 'sqlite.db' -exec sqlite3 "{}" 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1="value"' | grep value \;
```

**EDIT:**

The above doesn't work since exec cannot handle pipes.
see [How do I include a pipe | in my linux find -exec command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307015/how-do-i-include-a-pipe-in-my-linux-find-exec-command)

```
find . -name "*.db" -type f | while read file ; do sqlite3 $file "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1='value'" | grep value ; if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo $file ; fi done
```

This I have tested and it works, but I am not sure whether this is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thx. And this gives me grep: ';: No such file or directory'
'find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"'. Am I missing sth.

Comment: `find` with `exec` can handle a pipe just fine, but you need to invoke a shell:  `find . -exec sh -c 'echo {} | grep .' \;`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exit status and test it in an if statement in order to do what you want.

The way to get this status is using `$?` variable. Here is a tutorial about it: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

If you want to add more code after `find` command, you can have a look to `xargs` to execute a shell script for each output line found by `find`, passing the results as arguments using `xargs`:

```
find . -name 'sqlite.db' | xargs <your_script>.sh
```

Besides, another solution in your case could be using `AWK` to execute the query for each `find` output row and analyze its result separately:

```
find . -name 'sqlite.db' | awk '{system("sqlite3 ..."); if () {} else {} }' -
```

Comment: exec itself checks for the return status, and prints the file only when the status is sucess (0), so I think there is no need check explicitly.