# Unix Find Passing Filename to Exec and In Output Redirect

Tags: unix, find, pipe, io-redirection

I want to base64 encode a directory of images removing newlines in the base64 output. I then save this as `<imageName>.base64.txt`.

I can do this using the following `for` loop:

```sh
  for file in $(find path/to/images -name "*.png"); do
    base64 "$file" | tr -d "\n" > "$file".base64.txt
  done
```

How would I do this with `find` using `xargs` or `-exec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very closely a dupe of [How do I include a pipe `|` in my linux find -exec command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307015/5291015), but does not cover the case you are dealing with.

To get the filename, you can run a `-exec sh -c` loop

```
find path/to/images -name "*.png" -exec sh -c '
     for file; do 
         base64 "$file" | tr -d "\n" > "${file}.base64.txt" 
     done' _ {} +
```

Using `find -exec` with `+` puts all the search results from `find` in one shot to the little script inside `sh -c '..'`. The `_` means invoke an explicit shell  to run the script defined inside `'..'` with the filename list collected as arguments.

An alternate version using `xargs` which is equally expensive as the above loop would be to do below. But this version separates filenames with `NUL` character `-print0` and `xargs` reads it back delimiting on the same character, both GNU specific flags

```
find path/to/images -name "*.png" -print0 |
    xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'base64 {} | tr -d "\n" > {}.base64.txt'
```